# How to analyse the oracle statspack which is in the html format?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, storage, oracle11g, oracle9i

I have a html version of the Oracle Statspack report.  I am trying to interpret the data on the report to extract a number of different values but I'm not sure where to look.  In particular, I am trying to find

- the number of queries to the database
- the number of commits
- the number of rollbacks
- writes into the database
- the number of sessions
- the amount of network traffic
- initial volume
- volume increase rate

Anyone with any idea as how to get these values as they are not obvious from the html? Sorry, I can't share the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information should all be in the load profile section at the very top of the Statspack report.  Taking [this sample report](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2248685#2248685) as an example

```
Load Profile
~~~~~~~~~~~~                            Per Second       Per Transaction
                                   ---------------       ---------------
                  Redo size:             71,177.49              4,528.86
              Logical reads:             38,275.00              2,435.35
              Block changes:                419.22                 26.67
             Physical reads:              6,416.62                408.27
            Physical writes:                123.09                  7.83
                 User calls:              1,448.24                 92.15
                     Parses:                467.38                 29.74
                Hard parses:                  0.41                  0.03
                      Sorts:                475.13                 30.23
                     Logons:                  7.20                  0.46
                   Executes:              2,101.90                133.74
               Transactions:                 15.72

  % Blocks changed per Read:    1.10    Recursive Call %:     68.39
 Rollback per transaction %:    0.10       Rows per Sort:    250.70
```

Executes is the number of SQL statements that are executed.  In this case, 2,101.9 queries were executed on average per second and 133.74 were executed on average per transaction.

Transactions is the number of transactions (i.e. the number of commits + the number of rollbacks).  In this case, there were on average 15.72 per second.

Rollback per transaction % is the percentage of transactions that were rollbacks.  Since just 0.10% of the transactions were rollbacks, 99.9% of the transactions were commits.  You could combine the that fraction with the total number of transactions to get the number of commits per second and the number of rollbacks per second if you so desired.

For the additional items you're interested in

What does the number of sessions mean to you?  Potentially, you want the number of new sessions that are created which would probably be the Logons value, i.e. an average of 7.20 sessions were created every second.

Are you interested in the volume of network traffic or in the amount of time spent waiting on network communication?  Statistics like

```
bytes received via SQL*Net from c        166,752,176      114,213.8      7,267.2
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client         282,458,320      193,464.6     12,309.7
```

tell you that roughly 159 MB of data was sent to the database from the clients over the duration of the snapshot while roughly 269 MB of data was sent to the clients from the database.

I don't know what you mean by "initial volume" or "volume increase rate".  What volume are you measuring?  What rate of increase are you measuring?

Comment: Thankyou Justin Cave. There are few more attributes that i need to get the values of - Number of sessions, Network Traffic,Initial Volume, Volume increase rate...is there a doc which can explain these things clearly as you did above?

Comment: @Nohsib - I'm not aware of any documentation that explains every term on the statspack report, no.  Jonathan Lewis has an excellent series of articles on interpreting statspack reports http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/statspack-examples/ but that is more focused on helping you figure out which information is likely to be meaningful than on defining every field in the report.

Comment: will go through the link..thanks..if you could kindly share your knowledge as how to interpret these - Number of sessions, Network Traffic,Initial Volume, Volume increase rate

Comment: @Nohsib - I edited your question to add these attributes and edited my answer to try to answer your additional questions.

Comment: Thankyou for editing the question and answering accordingly..I could not understand how you got the numbers 159Mb & 269Mb? and by initial volume i ment the initial size of the dB and and volume increase rate is the rate at which the dB's size is growing...and does physical writes mean the inserts/updates into the dB?

Comment: @Nohsib - The first number is the number of bytes received from/ sent to the client.  166,752,176 bytes divided by 1024 is approximately 163 kb.  Divided by 1024 again is approximately 159 MB.  A statspack report will not indicate the size of a database or the rate of growth of the database.  You'd need to gather that information elsewhere (potentially from `DBA_SEGMENTS` or `DBA_DATA_FILES` or other data dictionary views depending on exactly how you define the size of a database).  Physical writes is the number of blocks physically written to disk.

Comment: so 3 queries on the same : #1.So Logon indicates the number of sessions into the dB, i thought there will be only one logon and then muliple sessions will be spawned ?? #2. if physical writes are those that you mentioned, than how to get the number of inserts/updates to the dB?
#3. I have uploaded the memory stats from my stats here - http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=NebUw and it shows lot of memory related details so wanted to confirm again if we cant get the initial db size and increase rate?

Comment: From Justin :: Memory statistics are generally unrelated to what most people consider the size of a database and almost certainly are unrelated to what most people consider the growth of a database over time. The memory allocated to Oracle is generally fixed (which buffers are given that memory may change over time) and is at best loosely correlated with the amount of data on disk. Assuming you are trying to measure the "size of the database" in terms of space allocated on disk, that's not in Statspack.

Comment: From Justin :: If you are defining the "number of inserts/ updates" to be the number of distinct INSERT/ UPDATE SQL statements executed during the window or the number of times those SQL statements are executed, that's probably not available. You could likely get close by looking at the top SQL and counting up the number of executions for any INSERT or UPDATE statements you see there. But Statspack does not attempt to capture every SQL statement so you'd be missing potentially quite a bit.

Comment: @ Justin : is there a way to get the maximum value to which the dB is configured for  all the parameters that we are discussing?

Comment: @Nohsib - There is, in general, no maximum configured value for these parameters.  It depends on a host of factors like your hardware and the specifics of what your SQL statements are doing, the plans the optimizer chooses, etc.

Comment: I ment like " SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions'; " which gives the maximum number of sessions that are permitted on the dB, can we have similar queries to get the max configured values for the rest?

Comment: @Nohsib - There is, in general, no maximum configured value for these parameters.  The maximum number of sessions is the exception.  There is no configured limit on the number of SQL statements executed, the number of rows updated, the number of transactions, the amount of data sent over the network, the size of the database, etc.  The limits are whatever your hardware, database configuration, and code can manage.

Comment: @ Justin : Oh ok!!! but can we get these info from the database configuration? if yes then how to?

Comment: @Nohsib - You could do a stress test to determine how your particular code running on your particular hardware with your particular database configuration scales.